# ASP.Net / C#.Net - PDF Library with template / replacement function for invoices

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I am trying to build my own web application and searching a PDF library which allows me to load files (e.g. pdf /  word document) as template and add more lines / replace placeholders.

I have my company styled word document and want to use it, not to build new, because I think it's a lot of work to do there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice without resorting to the Adobe Acrobat API is [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

There are 2 very important reasons to not use Adobe Acrobat.

1. It is not thread safe at all.
2. It is **ridiculously slow**!

Comment: No problem with trusting you, but can you discribe why?